# Can´t install Xampp on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation, xampp

I'm trying to install Xampp but those errors appeared when I followed some of the steps shown in other posts.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You where told to make the file executable by doing a "chmod 775" on the file; please do so when doing the command in the 1st image. And please please to avoid this kind of problems: install the normal LAMP Canonical provided for us. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP This will install without problems and will have you end with a "it works" webpage.

Comment: Also, we prefer *text output*, rather than a limited screenshoot.

Comment: Though screenshot is way better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To install XAMPP, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run/download
```

Once downloaded, just run:

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

This will start the install.  See image below.

[image]